# Kinect 3D character mesh animation

Tags: java, animation, kinect, processing, 3d-model

I am writing with Java and Processing, trying to animate a character with data received from Kinect. I have been successful in creating a stick man that repeats my motion. However, I find that doing a 3D mesh, loaded from an OBJ file is much harder than that. I have been searching all over the internet to find any info on that and could not find anything sensible. I know that it might involve bones and such but, again, there is no library for doing that, no article touching that subject. I would appreciate any help - suggestions, libraries, sources, links..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're exporting OBJ files, you're exporting meshes/geometry, not motion/animation data.
I recently started working on an animation exporter using Processing and the [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/) using the [BVH](http://tech-artists.org/wiki/BVH)(Biovision motion capture format) file format as you can easily get joint positions and orientation with the library.

I then pondered if maybe somebody already did this (as it's fairly straightforward), and yes,people did already do work on this:

- [Brekel Kinect with BVH](http://www.brekel.com/?p=341) support, [Brekel BVH and Blender](http://www.blendernation.com/2011/07/22/kinect-brekel-bvh-import-to-blender-2-57b/)
- [Kinect data and FBX export](http://vimeo.com/19751821) draft.

There is room for improvement though.
Depending on how comfortable you ware with programming, you might want to start with BVH, since it's a plain text format. The thing that worries me most about this format though,
is the fact that is is using Euler angles. Also consider using [FBX](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=7478532) as it's a more up to date format with more options.

In short, don't use a file format for storing geometry, use one for animation/bones.